# Hottowel converting to Durandal 2 issue

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I was working on a Hottowel project and I updated to Durandal 2.0. I have followed the [Converting from 1.x to 2.0 guide](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/), but I still have some problems:

**1.** Loading `router` plugin always times out, except if I load it like this:

```
app.configurePlugins({
        dialog: true,
        router: true
    }, '../durandal/plugins');
```

Note the path parameter.

**2.** I can no longer transition from one module to another. The only way a module can load is if I refresh the page with the specific hash in URL. When I click on a navigation button, the hash in the browser URL changes, but the module is not loaded. Also, `router.isNavigating` is stuck on `true`.

Here are the files:

`main.js`

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        'services' : 'services'
    }
});

define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);

define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'durandal/system', 'services/logger'],
    function (app, viewLocator, system, logger) 
        system.debug(true);

        app.title = 'MyApp';

        app.configurePlugins({
            dialog: true,
            router: true
        }, '../durandal/plugins');

        app.start().then(function () {
            viewLocator.useConvention();

            app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
        });
});
```

`shell.js`

```
define(['durandal/plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'services/logger', 'services/authentication', 'config'],
function (router, app, logger, authentication, config) {
    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            router.map(config.routes)
                .buildNavigationModel()
                .mapUnknownRoutes('home');

            logger.log('Application loaded', {}, 'shell', true);

            return router.activate();
        },
        authentication: authentication
    };
});
```

`config.routes`

```
[
    { route: ['', 'home'],  moduleId: 'viewmodels/home',       title: 'Home',      nav: true, caption: '<i class="icon-home"></i> Home' },
    { route: 'mainMenu',    moduleId: 'viewmodels/mainMenu',   title: 'Main Menu', nav: true, caption: '<i class="icon-th-list"></i> Main Menu' },
    { route: 'logIn',       moduleId: 'viewmodels/logIn',      title: 'Log In',    nav: false },
    { route: 'profile',     moduleId: 'viewmodels/profile',    title: 'Profile',   nav: false },
    { route: 'admin',       moduleId: 'viewmodels/admin',      title: 'Admin',     nav: false }
]
```

Example of a viewmodel: `viewmodels/logIn.js`

```
define(['services/logger', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/authentication'],
    function (logger, router, authentication) {
        var userName = ko.observable(),
            password = ko.observable(),
            rememberMe = ko.observable();

        function activate() {
            logger.log('Log in view activated', null, 'logIn', true);
            return true;
        }

        function logIn() {
            authentication.logIn(userName(), password(), rememberMe());
        }

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            userName: userName,
            password: password,
            rememberMe: rememberMe,
            logIn: logIn
        };

        return vm;
});
```

**EDIT**

`shell.html`

```
<div>
    <header>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
    </header>
    <section id="content" class="main container">
        <!--ko compose: {
                model: router.activeItem, 
                afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
                transition: 'entrance'
            } -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </section>
    <footer>
        <!--ko compose: {view: 'footer'} --><!--/ko-->
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your compose binding in the Shell view?

Comment: Added `shell.html` code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in the view composition. That was also updated in the new version. It should be:

```
<div id="content" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance' }"></div>
```

instead of

```
<!--ko compose: {
        model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
        transition: 'entrance'
    } -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Thanks to @margabit for pointing me to shell.html.

Comment: Oh! I didn't check the Edit! I thought it would be there but I wanted to be sure. Happy you fixed it! Enjoy :)

Comment: you could use your compose binding, just should have added params  attached: router.attached, compositionComplete: router.compositionComplete

Answer (score 2):

I think your second problem is a bug in Durandal which has now been fixed, however it probably isn't in the Nuget package yet.

Try this:

Go to about line 353 in Scripts/Durandal/composition.js and change this line

```
if (instruction.cacheViews != undefined && !instruction.cacheViews)
```

to this:

```
if (instruction != undefined && !instruction.cacheViews)
```

Does that fix your problem?

Comment: Well, it fixes my problem, thanks, I think it's registered here: https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/276